# Is this similar to knapsack or Change-making algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, knapsack-problem

> this problem involves trying to fit items of
>   different weights into a bag so that the  bag ends up with a
>   specified total weight or closest to total specified weight.

**Example 1 :-
Bag can hold max up to 240 kg of weight**

Item1- 60kg, Item2- 30kg, Item3- 55kg,Item4- 60kg,Item5- 80kg, Item6- 40kg, Item7- 7kg,

Here selected item should be Item1, Item4, Item5 and Item6(60+60+80+40 = 240 kg)

**Example 2 :-
Bag can hold max up to 180 kg of weight**

Item1- 60kg, Item2- 30kg, Item3- 55kg,Item4- 30kg,Item5- 70kg, Item6- 48kg

Here selected item should be Item1, Item4, Item5 and Item6(60+70+48 = 178 kg)

which is closest to 180 kg

**Here is my template method**

```
public List getSelectedItems(List<Presentation> inputList, int knapsackCapacity){
List selectItems;

// optimized algorith  which returns selectItems and inputList containing  the 
//left out items i.e which are not selected;

return selectItems;
}
```

Some people on net call it simplest form of [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)  as it does not have any benifit/profit associated with it and some call it [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)

Whatever category it comes under i could not get algorithm for this and hence not able to make java program out of it. Any help here ?

Comment: knapsack is np hard. if you can "optimize" its solution, you are due for a nobel price, at least. probably also assassination from a few spy agencies…

Comment: @hop there is a pseudo-polynomial solution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming

Comment: @hop do you mean to say recursion is the only way to go at this point of time till some somebody comes up with better solution ?

Comment: @MSach: no, i'm not meaning to say that, at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be solved optimally in pseudo-polynomial time (`O(nW)`) using Dynamic Programming. What you have to do is modify a little the solution for Knapsack 0/1 like this:

```
if w[i] > W
    m[i,W] = m[i-1,W]
else if W - m[i-1, W] < W - m[i-1, W - w[i]] + w[i]
    m[i,W] = m[i-1,W]
else
    m[i-1, W - w[i]] + w[i]
```

Where `W` is the weight limit, `w` is the array of element weights. The difference is that you have to minimize the difference between `W` and the result, instead of maximizing the sum of the values.

Here is the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem) solution with the required modifications:

```
// Input:
// Weights (stored in array w)
// Number of distinct items (n)
// Knapsack capacity (W)
for j from 0 to W do
  m[0, j] := 0  // Initialize to 0
end for 
for i from 1 to n do    // for every element in the array
  for j from 0 to W do  // for every possible weight
    if w[i] > j then    // if the element's weight is higher than the max
      m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]  // use the solution that excludes the element
    // else if the diff between the solution that excludes the element and max weight
    // is smaller than the one that uses it, use the former.
    else if (j - m[i-1, j]) < (j - m[i-1, j - w[i]] + w[i])
      m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]
    // else use the element's weight in the solution
    else
      m[i, j] := m[i-1, j - w[i]] + w[i]
    end if
```

The 2D array `m`, is the memoization table, at the end of the algorithm, `m[k, p]` holds the best solution for elements from 0 to `k` with maximum weight `p`.

EDIT: I implemented and tested it in `C++`, it should be easy to port to Java:

```
template<typename T>
long Weight(const T& w, int size, const int W)
{
    vector<vector<int>> m(size+1, vector<int>(W+1, 0));

    for(int i = 1; i <= size; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= W; ++j)
        {
            if(w[i-1] > j)
            {
                m[i][j] = m[i-1][j];
            }
            else if((j - m[i-1][j]) < (j - (m[i-1][j - w[i-1]] + w[i-1])))
            {
                m[i][j] = m[i-1][j];
            }
            else
            {
                m[i][j] = m[i-1][j - w[i-1]] + w[i-1];
            }
        }
    }

    return m[size][W];
}
```

Comment: what is m ? if you could explain this it would be great help.

Comment: In Dynamic Programming you always need a memoization table to record previously found solutions, that is what `m` is, you can just use a 2D array with dimensions `W` and `n`, where `n` is the number of elements.

Comment: Thanks. I am not able to make out what your algo is trying to do here. Can you explain it . Thanks in advance. I simply broke my head but could not able to break the solution for it

Comment: some folks like at https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2013-December/662545.html even suggest thats its not exactly the knapsack problem but a Change-making_problem making problem as it does not have value associated with it

Comment: imreal i spotted the java code at http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-knapsack-algorithm/ but not able to figure out how to eliminate value constraint from this as i just weight constraint. Can you help here ?

Comment: Sure, but I am not home right now, I'll check it out tonight

Comment: I modified the code in the dzone.com link and it seems to work, check it out here: http://ideone.com/w8Y5XQ

Comment: Thanks imreal. I am expecting output to be possible combination of elements  whose sum is equal to or closest to 240

Comment: @MSach you can get that from the table output, backtracking.

Comment: imreal actually i went thru couple of videos on youtube . Most of them help in how memory table is filled out which i understood now except one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH7weFvjLPY. But i did not get his explaination of backtracking here. Sorry for being laymen here. But whenever you have few mins can you help here. Somehow i want to get this logic badly

Answer (score 0):

I like this question so just want to share  my approach

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    List<Presentation> l = new ArrayList<Presentation>();
    Presentation p1=new Presentation("one",20);
    Presentation p2=new Presentation("two",20);
    Presentation p3=new Presentation("three",20);
    Presentation p4=new Presentation("four",20);
    Presentation p5=new Presentation("five",20);
    Presentation p6=new Presentation("six",20);
    Presentation p7=new Presentation("seven",20);
    Presentation p8=new Presentation("eight",20);
    Presentation p9=new Presentation("nine",20); 
    Presentation p10=new Presentation("ten",90);
    Presentation p11=new Presentation("eleven",90);
    l.add(p1);
    l.add(p2);
    l.add(p3);
    l.add(p4);
    l.add(p5);
    l.add(p6);
    l.add(p6);
    l.add(p7);
    l.add(p8);
    l.add(p9);
    l.add(p10);
    l.add(p11);
    System.out.println(getSelectedItems(l,200));
  }

  private static List<String>  getSelectedItems(List<Presentation> l, int knapsackCapacity) {
    int sum=0;
    int temp=0;
    PresentationCompare compare=new PresentationCompare();
    List<String> s=new ArrayList<String>();
    while(sum!=knapsackCapacity && sum<knapsackCapacity && l.size()!=0){
      Presentation maxObj=Collections.max(l,compare);
      temp+=maxObj.getWeight();
      if(temp<=knapsackCapacity){
        sum=temp;
        s.add(maxObj.getName());
        l.remove(l.indexOf(maxObj));
      }else{
        l.remove(l.indexOf(maxObj));
        temp=sum;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }



}
```

---

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class PresentationCompare implements Comparator<Presentation> {

  public int compare(Presentation o1, Presentation o2) {
    return o1.weight-o2.weight;
  }

}
```

Comment: what you are trying to do here ?

Comment: taking max value one after another  and adding until sum what i required get or all the element get added

Answer (score 0):

I agree with imreal analysis. But this can be solved this without any modification to knapsack solution. Just consider the value of weights same as weights. Then we we don't have to modify the knapsack program .Here is the example

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Knapsack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] weight = {60, 30, 55, 60, 80, 40, 7};
        int[] value = {60, 30, 55, 60, 80, 40, 7};
        int targetSum = 31;

        knapsack(weight, value, targetSum);

    }

    public static void knapsack(int[] weight, int[] value, int targetSum) {

        int[][] weightValMatrix = new int[weight.length + 1][targetSum + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < targetSum + 1; k++) {
                weightValMatrix[i][k] = 0;
            }

        }

        for (int i = 1; i < weight.length + 1; i++) {
            for (int k = 1; k < targetSum + 1; k++) {
                if (k < weight[i - 1]) {
                    weightValMatrix[i][k] = weightValMatrix[i - 1][k];
                } else {
                    int valueInclusiveCurrentWeight = value[i - 1];
                    if ((k - weight[i - 1]) > 0) {
                        valueInclusiveCurrentWeight = valueInclusiveCurrentWeight
                                + weightValMatrix[i - 1][k - weight[i - 1]];
                    }

                    int valueExcludingCurrentWeight = weightValMatrix[i - 1][k];
                    weightValMatrix[i][k] = valueInclusiveCurrentWeight >= valueExcludingCurrentWeight ? valueInclusiveCurrentWeight
                            : valueExcludingCurrentWeight;

                }

            }



        }



        for (int i = 1; i < weight.length + 1; i++) {

            for (int k = 1; k < targetSum + 1; k++) {

                System.out.print(weightValMatrix[i][k]);

                if(k == targetSum){
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("final value is " + weightValMatrix[weight.length][targetSum]);

        List<Integer> finallySelectedWeightIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        findActualWeightIndex(weightValMatrix, weight.length, targetSum, finallySelectedWeightIndex, weight);

        for(int index:finallySelectedWeightIndex){
            System.out.println("weight is " + weight[index-1] + " value is "+ value[index-1]);
        }


    }


    public static void findActualWeightIndex(int[][] weightValMatrix, int row, int column, 
            List<Integer> finallySelectedWeightIndex, int[] weight) {

        if(row==0 || column==0){
            return;
        }

        if(weightValMatrix[row][column]==weightValMatrix[row-1][column]){
            findActualWeightIndex(weightValMatrix, row-1, column, finallySelectedWeightIndex, weight);
        }else{
            finallySelectedWeightIndex.add(row);
            findActualWeightIndex(weightValMatrix, row-1, column - weight[row-1] , finallySelectedWeightIndex, weight);
        }
    }

}
```